# Proving that a product of maps is linear

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations

I have two maps $\gamma, \beta: [0,1] \to M_n (\mathbb{R})$, both of which are continuous, and consider the product map $\gamma \beta: [0,1] \to M_n (\mathbb{R})$. I'm trying to show that $\gamma \beta$ is linear and therefore continuous. I'm ok with the fact that linear implies continuous, but other than the conceptual understanding that matrix multiplication is a composition of linear transformations, I can't show that this map is linear. In particular, I have to show that
$$
\forall a,b \in [0,1], \; (\gamma \beta)(a+b) = (\gamma \beta)(a) + (\gamma \beta)(b) \\ 
\forall \lambda \in [0,1], \forall a \in [0,1], \; (\gamma \beta)(\lambda a) = \lambda (\gamma \beta)(a). 
$$
I'm a bit stumped on proving both of these. For the latter, I fix $\lambda, a\in [0,1]$, and we have
\begin{align*}
(\gamma \beta)(\lambda a) = (\gamma)(\lambda a) \beta(\lambda a) = \lambda^2 \gamma(a) \beta (a),
\end{align*}
and I'm already stuck because I have an extra factor of $\lambda$.

Is this map linear? If so, I would appreciate some advice on how to prove it.

Comment: The product map is your questions defined as $\gamma\beta(t)=\gamma(t)\beta(t)$ ? (matrix multiplication of the image

Comment: Without specific information I don't think you can even say $\gamma,\beta$ are linear ... so you cannot prove $\gamma\beta$ linear in this way

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 This is the map I had in mind, yes.

Comment: @AryanDugar Yes, that sounds sounds good. Is that different from what I had? (I may be missing something.)

Comment: I am sorry! Your notation suggested composition to me, because you wrote $\gamma \beta:[0,1] \rightarrow ...$ and your notation with $(\gamma \beta)$.

Comment: @AryanDugar Yes, very sorry about that. I've used that notation for both product and composition, and I should've been clearer.

Comment: I suppose it is right that, because of what you have above with the square of lambda, this is not a linear map (given $\gamma, \beta$ are linear).

Comment: Yeah I agree, even $\gamma,\beta$ are linear, their product is not.

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 This makes sense to me based on the map, but isn't matrix multiplication itself linear/continuous? I'm trying to reconcile that fact with the fact that this map isn't.

Comment: Matrix multiplication $*:A,B\to AB$ is linear in each of its argument $A,B$, it doesn't mean it's linear in the parameter of the $\gamma,\beta$

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 That makes much more sense. What about matrix inversion? The map $*: A \to A^{-1}$ seems to me that it should be linear, but $(A+B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} + B^{-1}$, so I think my intuition is incorrect.

Comment: It's definitely not linear as you have showed... $(kA)^{-1}=\frac 1k A^{-1}$. May you can train your intuition of the "linearity" better in this process :D